# ‘wenn, dann’ in German vs 'If, then' in English

Tags: word-usage

If English, it is not good to say 'if ..., then...'. But in German, it seems that it is quite normal to say 'wenn..., dann ...'.

Can the 'dann' be omitted like in English?

Comment: The typical combination in German is *wenn.., dann*. I don't understand, what you mean by *emit*: pronounciation? If so, there is a separate tag for it.

Comment: Maybe you mean the construction *'If at all, then ...'*? This can actually be translated to *'"Wenn überhaupt, dann..."* or shortly *"Wenn, dann..."*. But please specify your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can the 'dann' be omitted like in English?

Short answer: yes

In english, instead of "if you're sick, then go to the doctor" you can say "if you're sick, go to the doctor".

In german it's the same, the "dann" is not needed (in natural speech). You can say "Wenn du krank bist, dann geh zum Arzt!" or "Wenn du krank bist, geh zum Arzt".

Comment: Fortgeschrittene lassen auch noch das *wenn* weg :)
Bist Du krank, geh zum Arzt!